# Insert data in MySQL DB in parallel using threads - C++

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading

I have a C++ program that inserts large amounts of data in to a database using bulk insert statements to improve performance. I'm also using threads to run these insert in parallel. Basically, I have a big text file that I break into parts. I then create threads to parse each part and populate a list of objects. Once a thread is populated, it connects to the database and  inserts the data in batches of 1000. each thread has a separate connection to the database. The threading boost the time taken to parse the file considerably, but when it comes to inserting into the database, there is no performance improvement at all. This leads me to believe that when inserting the batches, the threads wait for each other. Is there a way that this could be prevented and they could run in parallel? I have an auto-incrementing primary key in the table and it occurs to me that this could be a reason for not allowing the parallel inserts?

My code looks like this:

```
void ThreadFunction(const char* filepath)
{
    TranscriptGBFFParser parser;
    list<RefSeqTranscript> transcripts; 
    parser.ParseFile(transcripts, filepath);

    RefSeqTranscript transcript;
    int success = transcript.ConnectDB("<host>", "<db>", "<pass>", "<schema>");

    if(success == 0)
    {
        cout << "Thread connected to database. Batch inserts commencing..." << endl;        

        transcript.InsertTranscripts(transcripts, 1000);

        transcript.CloseConnection();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connection attempt failed" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Thread execution completed." << endl;  
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[] )
{   
    const char* filepath = argv[1];
    const char* outputDir = argv[2];
    int numThreads = atoi(argv[3]);

    TranscriptGBFFParser parser;

    cout << "Counting transcripts in " << filepath << "..." << endl;

    list<string> filepaths;

    if(numThreads > 1)
    {
        int numTranscripts = parser.CountTranscriptsInFile(filepath);
        int transcriptsPerFile = numTranscripts/numThreads + 1;

        cout << numTranscripts << " Transcripts in file..." << endl;    
        cout << "Splitting file into " << numThreads << " files with approximately " << transcriptsPerFile << " transcripts per file..." << endl;

        filepaths = parser.SplitFile(filepath, outputDir, transcriptsPerFile);
    }
    else
    {
        filepaths.push_back(filepath);
    }

    boost::thread_group group;  
    for (std::list<string>::iterator it = filepaths.begin(); it != filepaths.end(); it++)
    {
        boost::thread *t = new boost::thread(ThreadFunction, (*it).c_str());
        group.add_thread(t);        
    }

    cout << "Waiting for threads to finish executing..." << endl;
    group.join_all();
    cout << "All threads completed execution. Exiting..." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the bottleneck is not on the database or on the connection?

Comment: I'm not. How could I get around this if it is?

Comment: You need to identify your bottleneck first. If your database is local, then the connection will probably not be an issue. Check the system load caused by your database then (for example). If you connect to a dedicated db server, you can maybe get a hint if you check your network traffic